# imageview like a slideshow

Tags: android, imageview, slideshow, ontouchlistener, touch-event

Hello guys I want to use a ImageView as a slideshow, that touch you on the right of the screen display the next image and if the touch is on the left show the previous image,
I already tried to implement this function but I get no response from the ImageView, looking logcat I realized that it doesn't dispatch of TouchEvent.

```
public class Prova4Activity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ImageView image;
Bitmap trash = loadImageFromUrl("http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/tt4web/   Nazionale/16_9_page-100.6.png");
ImageView imgpag;
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.EDGE_RIGHT){
    trash.recycle();
     trash = null;
     trash = loadImageFromUrl("http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/tt4web/Nazionale/16_9_page-100.6.png");
     image.setImageBitmap(trash);

     }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.EDGE_LEFT){
         trash.recycle();
         trash = null;
         trash = loadImageFromUrl("http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/tt4web/  Nazionale/16_9_page-100.5.png");
         imgpag.setImageBitmap(trash);

     }
imgpag.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

return true;
}
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    imgpag = (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.imgpag); 
    imgpag.setImageBitmap(trash);
    imgpag.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }
}
```

I would not use a gallery because the images are small and do not know in advance the number of images because i load them directly from Inernet based on the actions of the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be not the best way to achieve this but you can try following:

Set two buttons on Screen - One on Right corner and One on the left corner.
(If you are showing ImageView full screen then better to use FrameLayout - 
bt make sure that Buttons are on the front)
Set Button properties like

`<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" android:background="@null"/>`

This will make sure that buttons are invisible

Then just add your logic of prev and next on OnClickListeners of these buttons

Hope this will help you